# How to setup a store module using Vue3 with Vuex4 and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I want to get into Vue3 / Vuex4 using TypeScript but unfortunately the docs didn’t help much

https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html

As a beginner, I started with a simple issue tracking store module. Inside my issues module I created a index.ts file taking in the “global store instance” and registers itself

```
import {
  ActionContext,
  ActionTree,
  GetterTree,
  MutationTree,
  Store,
} from "vuex";

export default (store: Store<{}>): void => {
  store.registerModule("issues", {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
  });
};

export type Issue = {
  title: string;
  isOpen: boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
};

export type State = {
  issues: Issue[];
};

export type Getters = {
  issues(state: State): Issue[];
};

export type ActionAugments = Omit<ActionContext<State, State>, "commit"> & {
  commit<K extends keyof Mutations>(
    key: K,
    payload: Parameters<Mutations[K]>[1]
  ): ReturnType<Mutations[K]>;
};

export enum ActionType {
  SubmitIssue = "SubmitIssue",
}

export type Actions = {
  [ActionType.SubmitIssue](
    context: ActionAugments,
    submitIssuePayload: SubmitIssuePayload
  ): void;
};

export type SubmitIssuePayload = {
  issueTitle: string;
};

export enum MutationType {
  SubmitIssue = "SUBMIT_ISSUE",
}

export type Mutations = {
  [MutationType.SubmitIssue](state: State, payload: SubmitIssuePayload): void;
};

const state: State = {
  issues: [],
};

const getters: GetterTree<State, State> & Getters = {
  issues: function (state: State): Issue[] {
    return state.issues;
  },
};

const actions: ActionTree<State, State> & Actions = {
  [ActionType.SubmitIssue]: function (
    { commit }: ActionAugments,
    { issueTitle }: SubmitIssuePayload
  ): void {
    commit(MutationType.SubmitIssue, { issueTitle });
  },
};

const mutations: MutationTree<State> & Mutations = {
  [MutationType.SubmitIssue]: function (
    state: State,
    { issueTitle }: SubmitIssuePayload
  ): void {
    const issue: Issue = {
      title: issueTitle,
      isOpen: true,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    };

    state.issues.push(issue);
  },
};
```

Currently I’m stuck with the setup for some reasons:

- I copypasted the `ActionAugments` from Google. Do I really need to reinvent the ActionContext on my own to get access to the commit function?
- The setup is not correct yet. The function `store.registerModule` shows this error

.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(path: string, module: Module<State, {}>, options?: ModuleOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Type 'GetterTree<State, State> & Getters' is not assignable to type 'GetterTree<State, {}> | undefined'.
      Type 'GetterTree<State, State> & Getters' is not assignable to type 'GetterTree<State, {}>'.
        'string' index signatures are incompatible.
          Type 'Getter<State, State>' is not assignable to type 'Getter<State, {}>'.
            Property 'issues' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'State'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(path: string[], module: Module<State, {}>, options?: ModuleOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.ts(2769)
store.ts(26, 3): 'issues' is declared here.
index.d.ts(132, 3): The expected type comes from property 'getters' which is declared here on type 'Module<State, {}>'
```

which makes sense, because the global store instance is of type `Store<{}>` and my module seems to expect `Store<State>`

How would I fix this?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that module state type was specified in places where root state is expected, while they aren't same.

It's preferable to keep root state type as separate type and import instead of hardcoding it like `{}` because it can change with time.

It should be `store: Store<RootState>`, `GetterTree<State, RootState>`, etc. Where root state generic parameter affects the type of `rootState` in Vuex context.

Comment: sorry, I can't find `RootState`. Do I have to create it on my own? E.g. `export type RootState = {};`

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Hm unfortunately the code doesn't work for me. I can't register the getters, this is the code with the error message: https://pastebin.com/ngMpvbDA

Comment: The order should be opposite, fixed.

Comment: thanks for help. Based on https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-usestore-composition-function I'm trying to register the module and use it inside a component but unfortunately it seems the registration is wrong and my getter returns an undefined value. This is the updated code https://pastebin.com/YbSgKqmm

Comment: Ok it seems I have to create my own Store type but that didn't solve the problem. The updated code: https://pastebin.com/ZftUbyKy

Comment: It's unclear what the problem currently is. You shouldn't have `app.use(store, key)`. This should be done once per app where other plugins are registered, this is what the warning says.

Comment: when using `app.use(store, key)` then `store.getters.issues` returns `undefined`. When removing `app.use(store, key)` then the app crashes with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getters')`

Comment: You need to have `app.use(store)` once per app. No `key`. FWIW I don't use `registerModule` for modules that don't need to be added dynamically. Module object is just provided to root state `modules`

Comment: Hm I think I almost got it. So the registration part seems to work but I can't access the module getters in a Vue component https://pastebin.com/5hJs0xmd

Comment: What you call useIssuesStore is not issues store but root store. The module is namespaced, so are getters. It's supposed to be `store.getters["issues/issues"]`

Comment: ah ok, setting `namespaced` to false enables `issuesStore.getters.issues[0].title` :)

Comment: Btw it's still rootStore, not issuesStore. Vuex 4 doesn't have separate stores.

Comment: so you think this is wong? https://pastebin.com/GsmCDjA9 because this seems to work as expected

Comment: this works too but I loose the type safety then https://pastebin.com/5sh262JJ

Comment: It's semantically wrong to call it issues store because it's really root store. You didn't provide a type for useStore, it can't figure out it by magic. Should be `useStore<RootState>()`

Comment: sorry, yes, I changed it to `const store: Store<RootState> = useStore<RootState>();` but still, `store.getters` doesn't know about the `issues` property. So the code works but I get no code completion / suggestions. ( I'm using VSC with Vetur )

Comment: I took it from here https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-usestore-composition-function

Comment: Notice that it deals with root store with injection key. Afaik it won't do any good for modules. Yes, that's the problem with namespaced modules. Their type safety is still unsolved in Vuex 4. See https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1831 . Probably some third-party attempts may work like https://github.com/paroi-tech/direct-vuex

Comment: this looks interesting too https://github.com/posva/pinia

Comment: I switched to Pinia recently, particularly because of TS. Its API looks close to what Vuex 5 is expected to be.